# What are the consequences of price-capping non-perishables undergoing temporary demand-spikes?

Tags: supply-and-demand, price-control

Due to the recent coronavirus outbreak (2020 for future readers), many consumers worldwide are overstocking on non-perishable products like toilet papers and hand sanitizers, in order to avoid shortages producers and retailers respond by increasing their prices, the Argentinian government has responded to these price surges [by establishing maximum](https://preciosmaximos.argentina.gob.ar/) [prices for these products](https://www.clarin.com/economia/coronavirus-argentina-lista-completa-productos-precios-maximos-dispuso-gobierno_0_pupFwl8cB.html), official statements describe the objective of these measures is to prevent businesses from "taking advantage and making a profit out of the necessity and anguish of the people."

Is this an effective measure against speculation? Does price-capping have a negative effective on production output by reducing incentives and funding? Does price-capping reduce product availability? Does it improve the equality of its distribution?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, please let me know if "What are the consequences of" is too broad of a question, I can reduce the scope to a specific hypothesis on either product distribution or production output.